# Responsive background image of a div together with inner image

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a responsive background image of a div which has an img wrapped inside:
Something like this:

[image: responsive img]

I am using bootstrap.
Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
  <div class="device-laptop">
     <img src="img/test.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css:

```
device-laptop{
  background: url('../img/macpro.jpg') no-repeat;
  width: 363px;
  height: 208px;
  padding: 12px 45px 23px 43px;
  background-size:100%;
}

.device-laptop img{
  width: 274px;
  height: 172px;
}
```

This is the normal form. Now i want to make this responsive so when the background image is changed, the image inside to change also. Is there anyway to achieve this?

I tried:

```
.device-laptop{
  background: url('../img/macpro.jpg') no-repeat;
  /*width: 363px;*/
  background-size:100%;
  height: 208px;
}
```

this makes the background image be responsive but how can i make also the image go parallel with the background one?
Thnx

Comment: http://cssdevices.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Odd, From the provided css, it appears that `.device-laptop` is having a fixed width and height. Not sure how it will be fluid then?

Anyway, Utilizing `background-size:contain` option mentioned by @papa

.. If you're ok with altering your markup. Below will do the job.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/wf3U8/1/

HTML

```
<div class="some-awesome-laptop">
    <div class="some-awesome-wallpaper-wrapper">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150&text=text" class="some-awesome-wallpaper" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.some-awesome-laptop {
    background-image:url("http://placehold.it/270x180/aaa&text=a");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:270px;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:66%; /* aspect ratio of the image: (180/270)*100 */
    position:relative;

    -webkit-background-size:contain;
    -moz-background-size:contain;
    background-size:contain;

}

.some-awesome-wallpaper-wrapper {
    padding:10px;
}

.some-awesome-wallpaper { 
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size:cover` or `background-size:contain` to suite your needs. Cover might be the better option.